# How to use ViewModelCloser to close the View of the ViewModel?

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvmcross

In the MvvmCross v3, CustomerManagement example, the method `void RequestClose(IMvxViewModel viewModel)` closes the top `View`. How do you close the `View` of a `ViewModel` instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wouldn't use that ViewModelCloser method - although it could be extended if you want to.

MvvmCross v3 removed the previous `CloseViewModel` method - because it didn't really work across all platforms and across all presentation styles - across all of navigation controllers, splitviews, tabs, flyouts, popups, dialogs, etc.

To replace it, v3 introduces a new ViewModel call:

```
    protected bool ChangePresentation(MvxPresentationHint hint)
```

This is matched in the UIs with an IMvxViewPresenter method:

```
    void ChangePresentation(MvxPresentationHint hint);
```

To use this, you will need to:

1. Create a new Hint class - e.g. `public class CustomPresentationHint : MvxPresentationHint { /* ... */ }`
2. In each UI project, provide a custom presenter (normally by overriding `CreateViewPresenter()` in your `Setup.cs` class) - and in that custom presenter handle the `ChangePresentationHint` call:

   ```
         public void ChangePresentation(MvxPresentationHint hint)
         {
             if (hint is CustomPresentationHint)
             {
                  // your custom actions here
                  // - which may involve interacting with the RootFrame, with a NavigationController, with the AndroidFragment manager, etc
             }
         }
   ```
3. In your viewmodel, you can send a `CustomPresentationHint` when you want to.

I realise this is 'more work' than was required in vNext, but hopefully it's a more flexible, powerful approach.

Comment: I have look at ChangePresentation(MvxPresentationHint hint), I guess the hint can store MvxBundle with any information, However, the problem is I call ChangePresentation in ViewModel, I don't know how to pass the ViewModel related View to Presenter.

Comment: This is your code - you can do what you want to - e.g. you could add an `public IMvxViewModel ViewModelToClose {get;set;` property to your `CusomPresentationHint`

Comment: CustomPresentationHint hint = new CustomPresentationHint();
hint.ViewModelToClose = this;
ChangePresentation( hint );

The presenter only get the viewmodel, how to I find the corresponding View

Comment: That depends on how the view is presented. The presenter owns the views - every view is shown via ShowView in the presenter.

Comment: I think I just keep a view - viewmodel mapping in presenter

Comment: see also update in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16157597/what-is-the-best-way-to-handle-goback-for-the-different-mvvmcross-v3-platforms