# How to use a custom presenter in WPF?

Tags: c#, android, wpf, mvvmcross

I am doing an Android and WPF cross platform app. I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15919288/how-to-use-viewmodelcloser-to-close-the-view-of-the-viewmodel?lq=1) regarding creating my own custom presenter.

While that works fine in a Droid project, there isn't a CreateViewPresenter to override in my MvxWpfSetup derrived Setup class....

How do I go about supplying my own presenter in Wpf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The presenter is passed in to the setup class in wpf application

```
public class Setup : MvxWpfSetup
{
    public Setup(Dispatcher dispatcher, IMvxWpfViewPresenter presenter)
        : base(dispatcher, presenter)
    {
    }
```

This is created in the wpf App.Xaml.Mvx.cs file, so simply pass in your own implementation there instead.

Comment: Thanks! Can't believe I didn't see that! I was so focused on overriding like in Droid projects that I didn't follow the Setup class back to initialization.